# How can I style a SearchView according to its state?

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, searchview, android-styles

I'm trying to style a `SearchView` to display it differently when it is focused by the user, as in Amazon's app:

### Focused

[image: SearchView, focused]

### Not focused

[image: SearchView, not focused]

I see from [this article](https://philio.me/styling-the-searchview-with-appcompat-v21/) that starting with v21 one can use `styleable` attributes to customize the `SearchView`'s display, like `queryBackground`:

```
<!-- Background for the section containing the search query -->
    <attr name="queryBackground" format="reference" />
```

I tried setting a `drawable` for this property via my app's style:

#### Style

```
<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="queryBackground">@drawable/shape_search</item>
</style>
```

#### Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:padding="12dp"
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="0.3dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
            <padding android:bottom="0dip" android:left="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:top="0dip"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:padding="12dp"
               android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
            <padding android:bottom="0dip" android:left="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:top="0dip"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

However this does not work as expected: the first style is always selected, wether I am focusing the SearchView or not.
I tried using other state selectors like `state_active` or even `state_window_focused` which mentions *when a view's window has input focus*, but in each case focusing the SearchView didn't change its display.

### Is there a way to display this SearchView differently in those two states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's 05/06/2018
I think you had found the solution for you but I think my answer maybe helpful for other people
I use kotlin, if you use java, it's the same

In your view (activity, fragment,..):

```
 svSearch.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(object : View.OnFocusChangeListener {
        override fun onFocusChange(v: View?, hasFocus: Boolean) {
            svSearch.isSelected =  hasFocus
            // isIconified() return true if search view lost focus, this line handle for user press back button case
            // as default when user press back button, the search view lost focus but view doesn't change state (collapse if width = wrap_content) 
            svSearch.isIconified = !hasFocus
        }

 })
```

Selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false">
       // something 
    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">
       // something 
    </item>
</selector>
```